# x:Bind not binding to attached property

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

Can anybody chime in how this is done correctly? I get a compiler error in the generated code behind.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle x:Name="BlueRect" Width="100" Height="100" Grid.Row="1" Fill="Blue" />
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Grid.Row="{x:Bind BlueRect.(Grid.Row),Mode=OneWay}" Fill="Red" />
</Grid>
```

(this is just a minimal example, without the `Mode=OneWay` it obviously works, but I need that... Also, I'd like to do this with `{x:Bind}` not the traditional `{Binding}`)

Comment: can you post what error is?

Comment: something along the lines of `Rectangle` doesn't contain member `Row`

Comment: Try changing `x:Name` to `Name` on your `BlueRect`. Reading through the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204783.aspx), it looks like you're doing this right.

Comment: Seems like they missed that use case, works without mode, works with not attached properties like `Rect.Fill` with mode, and there is not a single example with that use case. Maybe you should report a bug to MS if there is no solution for some time.

Comment: @Bart yeah, I actually think it is a pretty simple error in the generated method, it's simply the wrong type being used there.

Comment: where would I submit this as a bug? Is there anyone that can do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Bind using the element name:

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Grid.Row="{Binding ElementName=BlueRect,Path=(Grid.Row),Mode=OneWay}" Fill="Red" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can report this on [Visual Studio connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/LoadSubmitFeedbackForm?FormID=6326).

I think you can consider work around this by calling `this.Bindings.Update()` when you change the row and keep x:bind OneTime.

For example, we may change the Grid.Row for "BlueRect" in a button click, and the following code shows how we can handle this scenario.

In XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle x:Name="BlueRect" Width="100" Height="100" Grid.Row="1" Fill="Blue" />
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Grid.Row="{x:Bind BlueRect.(Grid.Row)}" Fill="Red" />
    <Button Content="Click me" Grid.Row="3" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid.SetRow(BlueRect, 2);
    this.Bindings.Update();
}
```

`this.Bindings.Update()` can also be used when the data is loaded async, and the data may not be ready before x:bind be initialized.

Comment: It's nice that you told me about the Bindings.Update() but I think we can all agree, that this is not the solution to this bug. I can see all kinds of unwanted things to happen with that approach. The big advantage of `x:Bind` over `Binding` is supposed to be speed. That's why the binding mode of `OneTime` is the standard. This will not allow true `OneTime` bindings on the same view. Also, it's a maintainability nightmare. I filed a bug through the smiley icon in Visual Studio and I just hope this will be fixed asap, since it's actually just a simple mishap in the code generator.

Comment: Agree. So it's only a workaround for specific scenario. I will try to report this via internal way too, but cannot say when it can be fixed. X:Bind still has a long way to go.